# Does anyone know of any font families that 6, 9, 8, 0 look the same upside down as right side up?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-identification

Does anyone know of any font families that 6, 9, 8, 0 look exactly the same upside down as right side up? The 6 upside down would look like 9 and vice-verse. Thanks!

Comment: search for 'geometric sans' for some likely candidates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Font's that are very modular**, like [Variable](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/madtype/variable/), are a good place to look. Anything humanist or old style is going to have too much modulation to fit your requirement.

**Case in point, try a [search for "modular" at MyFonts](http://www.myfonts.com/search/tag%3amodular/fonts/)** and Variable and many others that fit your request come right up.

Comment: [Be kind, show a preview of the font please.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/be-kind-show-a-preview-of-the-font)

Answer (score 5):

As DA01 mentions, a search for "geometric sans" will give you great results. These are some of the ones listed under this category in [Font Shop](http://www.fontshop.com/fontlist/subclasses/sans_geometric/?&fg=000000&bg=ffffff&sample_size=36&sample_text=12669900886699&ft=liga), the 8s are more irregular, but you can probably find some that are completely symmetric.

Futura

[image]

Avenir

[image]

ICT Bauhaus

[image]

ICT Kabel

[image]

ICT Serif Gothic

[image]

Faricy

[image]

Transfer Superset

[image]

Comment: Avenir, Bauhaus, Serif Gothic, and Transfer all have the very common feature of vertical but not horizontal axis symmetry. In other words, you can tell when they're flipped on their heads..

Answer (score 0):

[Futura](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futura_(typeface)) is a popular one

[image]

But the 8 is slightly bigger on the bottom than on the top, now that I look at it in photoshop.

Comment: Futura follows a number of old style proportioning techniques. For this reason, it's characters are not truly geometric or modular.